# the private key for distribution is not installed on this mac

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

[image]

how to solve these errors

I can't create a new version for any of my apps?

Comment: Revoke certificate and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to your mac that has it installed
2. open keychain
3. find the distribution certificate and its private key (select them)
4. export the selected items. (as p12)
5. copy the p12 files to new mac
6. go back to your new mac
7. import the p12 files you created
8. check the keychain for the imported items
9. restart xcode for good measure